# Reading in a CSV file using while IFS= but not treating the comma as the separator if the field is in quotations

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, csv

I have a large CSV file where columns are separated by commas in each case. However, about 5% of the time the first column contains a comma within itself and is denoted this way by the fact that these fields will have quotations around them if they have a comma inside them.

What would be a good way to read in this file such that we don't treat commas as separators whenever they're contained within quotations?

The best way I am thinking of would be to do something complex with a stack or something to see if we're currently within quotations or not but I think there must surely be an easier way. Note: There are never quotations within quotations or any other corner cases beyond this one.

*examples:

1. Apple, 10, 12, ....
2. Banana, 5, 10, ...
3. "Banana, green", 3, 14, ... (Notice this line has a comma in it but it has quotations to indicate this)*

I would want to read in this last line into a variable as "Banana, green" rather than the default behavior which would  read in banana and green as separate variables.

Comment: The bash shell is just not the right tool for this imho - use a proper CSV parser such as that provided by the Python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), Perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module, or [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#reference)

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. If your CSV has a header line then make sure to include that.

Comment: Alongside csvkit and miller, there's GoCSV which has more options than csvkit and no syntax to learn like in miller.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\"" }
{
    print
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print "\t" i, "<" $i ">"
    }
    print "---"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Apple,10,12,...
        1 <Apple>
        2 <10>
        3 <12>
        4 <...>
---
Banana,5,10,...
        1 <Banana>
        2 <5>
        3 <10>
        4 <...>
---
"Banana, green",3,14,...
        1 <"Banana, green">
        2 <3>
        3 <14>
        4 <...>
---
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the logic for this? I don't understand the line BEGIN { FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\"" }

Comment: @Prospero I'm just describing a regexp that matches the contents of a field in a CSV - either a series of non-`,`s or a string within `"`s which can include `,`s. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content for more on `FPAT` and see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more on parsing CSVs with awk in general.